# VIM, when I shell to prompt using :!bash I'd like the command prompt to reflect me being in a shell

Tags: bash, vim, prompt

I am in vim all day lately, practicing code. Often times when I want to do something from the prompt - I will use a key binding for :!bash  and do what ever I need to do, then type exit to return to the vim script I am working on.

sometimes I forget that I am in a shell and need to poke around to find my script. Is there a way to set it up so that my prompt says "vim $:" or something similar?

I suppose I could try to create a `.bashrc_for_vim` and run `source .bashrc_for_vim` or something like that, but that seems pretty clunky.

Has anyone here figured out an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make use of the `$SHLVL` environment variable, described in `man bash` as

```
SHLVL  Incremented by one each time an instance of bash is started.
```

In my `~/.bashrc`:

```
# set a variable to reflect SHLVL > 1
if [[ $SHLVL -gt 1 ]] ; then
    export SUBSHELL="${SUBSHELL:+$SUBSHELL}+"
else
    export SUBSHELL=""

fi
```

I use this later in setting up my `PS1` to add a "+" for each level down.

```
if [[ "$color_prompt" = yes ]]; then
#             chroot?                       Depth      green       user@host nocolor  :   green      $PWD  ref      (status) off   $ or # space             
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}${SUBSHELL}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[1;31m\]($?)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}${SUBSHELL}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

In use, it looks like:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ uptime
 22:57:48 up 2 days,  9:51,  2 users,  load average: 2.23, 0.75, 0.41
             # start a subshell, see the first "+" appear
walt@bat:~(0)$ bash
             # start a 2nd subshell, see the second "+" appear
+walt@bat:~(0)$ bash
             # Start vim, then do :!bash
++walt@bat:~(0)$ vim foo

             # here, underneath vim, look at the process tree leading to here
+++walt@bat:~(0)$ ps -fp$$
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
walt      6803  6802  0 23:10 pts/21   00:00:00 bash
+++walt@bat:~(0)$ ps -fp$$,6802
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
walt      6802  6732  0 23:10 pts/21   00:00:00 vim foo
walt      6803  6802  0 23:10 pts/21   00:00:00 bash
+++walt@bat:~(0)$ ps -fp$$,6802,6732
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
walt      6732  6662  0 23:10 pts/21   00:00:00 bash
walt      6802  6732  0 23:10 pts/21   00:00:00 vim foo
walt      6803  6802  0 23:10 pts/21   00:00:00 bash
+++walt@bat:~(0)$ ps -fp$$,6802,6732,6662
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
walt      6662  5932  0 23:10 pts/21   00:00:00 bash
walt      6732  6662  0 23:10 pts/21   00:00:00 bash
walt      6802  6732  0 23:10 pts/21   00:00:00 vim foo
walt      6803  6802  0 23:10 pts/21   00:00:00 bash
+++walt@bat:~(0)$ ps -fp$$,6802,6732,6662,5932
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
walt      5932  5795  0 Jan29 pts/21   00:00:00 bash
walt      6662  5932  0 23:10 pts/21   00:00:00 bash
walt      6732  6662  0 23:10 pts/21   00:00:00 bash
walt      6802  6732  0 23:10 pts/21   00:00:00 vim foo
walt      6803  6802  0 23:10 pts/21   00:00:00 bash
+++walt@bat:~(0)$ ps -fp$$,6802,6732,6662,5932,5795
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
walt      5795  5070  0 Jan29 ?        00:00:37 /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
walt      5932  5795  0 Jan29 pts/21   00:00:00 bash
walt      6662  5932  0 23:10 pts/21   00:00:00 bash
walt      6732  6662  0 23:10 pts/21   00:00:00 bash
walt      6802  6732  0 23:10 pts/21   00:00:00 vim foo
walt      6803  6802  0 23:10 pts/21   00:00:00 bash
                # now unwind, returning to vim
+++walt@bat:~(0)$ exit

                # back in vim, :q!
Press ENTER or type command to continue
                # unwind
++walt@bat:~(0)$ exit
                # unwind
+walt@bat:~(0)$ exit
               # back at the top level
walt@bat:~(0)$ : and I'm out
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much! That works perfectly when I shell out, differently when I <CTRL Z>. One question though, what value is represented between the ( )'s, in your case (0)? The reason I ask is I did a <CRTL Z> from Vim and it didn't have the +, but it did have a value of (140) in red. there.

Answer (score 2):

Vim sets the `VIMRUNTIME` (and `VIM`) environment variables within the shell from `:sh` or `:!bash`, so you can detect it that way in your `.bashrc`:

```
if [ "$VIMRUNTIME" ]
then
    PS1="vim: $PS1"
fi
```

The above will prefix your existing prompt with "vim: ". You could change it to something else, like just `vim $:`, if you wanted. Put that at the end of the file so that your normal prompt has been set up by then, so you can either use it or replace it.

You can't do the same for <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> because that really *does* return you to your original shell - it's not a new session, it's the one you started `vim` from in the first place, so it has the same environment and settings as you started with.

Comment: that is really interesting, thank you for the information, I am going to give that a try!